# Typescript: lodash modify the stored value in a groupBy

Tags: typescript, group-by, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash to group by, and then I need to modify each group to have a heap in it.

I have an object which looks like so:

```
//pseudco code
type Pool = {
    address: string
    price: number
}

const poolGroups = _.groupBy(pools, x => `${x.address}`);
```

Now Id like to store each group as a heap instead of an array, I'd imagine it would looks something like so:

```
_.groupBy(poolGroup.map(g => { return {g.Key,  new Heap(g.values, minComparator) }), g.Key);
```

But that doesn't compile (sorry not my primary lanaguage)

How can modify the stored value in a lodash group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.mapValues()` to transform the values of the object created by `_.groupBy()`:

```
const poolGroups = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(pools, 'address'),
  group => new Heap(group, minComparator)
)
```

Comment: so each group is treated as an iterable! thanks